# No se estan dibujando todas las filas en el datatable apesar de que el bucle en el cual se llena recorre todo el arreglo

Tags: javascript, datatables

Hago una petición a un servlet, este me regresa 16 filas, estoy paginando y voy de 16 en 16

Pero las 16 filas no se dibujan, solo se dibujan 10, no se porque, el bucle recorre los 16 elementos pero no se porque razón no se dibujan las 16 filas, por cada vuelta creo una nueva fila y le meto los datos que le pertenecen segun la posicion del array.

Esta función es la que yo utilizo para llenar el datatable una vez llegan los resultados del servlet, el parámetro data es un arreglo de objetos que obtengo apartir del json que obtengo de una petición.

```
function putNewsInDataTable(data){


      let scrollBody = document.querySelector(".dataTables_scrollBody")

      for (let k = 0; k < data.length; k++){


         let row =  document.createElement("tr")
         let titleColumn = document.createElement("td")
         let optionsColumn = document.createElement("td")
         let datePost = document.createElement("td")

         let deleteOption = document.createElement("button")
         let iconDeleteOption = document.createElement("span")
         let restoreOption = document.createElement("button")
         let iconRestoreOption = document.createElement("span")
         let editOption = document.createElement("a")
         let iconEditOption = document.createElement("span")
         let hideOption = document.createElement("button")
         let iconHideOption = document.createElement("span")

         deleteOption.setAttribute("class","option-post remove")
         hideOption.setAttribute("class","option-post hide")
         restoreOption.setAttribute("class","option-post restore")
         editOption.setAttribute("class", "option-post edit")


         deleteOption.idEvento = data[k].idEvento
         hideOption.idEvento = data[k].idEvento
         restoreOption.idEvento = data[k].idEvento
         editOption.idEvento = data[k].idEvento

         iconRestoreOption.setAttribute("class","fa fa-trash-restore")
         iconDeleteOption.setAttribute("class","fa fa-trash")
         iconHideOption.setAttribute("class","fa fa-eye-slash")
         iconEditOption.setAttribute("class","fa fa-edit")

         restoreOption.appendChild(iconRestoreOption)
         deleteOption.appendChild(iconDeleteOption)
         editOption.appendChild(iconEditOption)
         hideOption.appendChild(iconHideOption)

         restoreOption.setAttribute("onclick","eventoController.updateStateNoticia(" + data[k].idEvento + ",4)")
         deleteOption.setAttribute("onclick","eventoController.updateStateNoticia(" + data[k].idEvento + ",2)")
         hideOption.setAttribute("onclick","eventoController.updateStateNoticia(" + data[k].idEvento + ",1)")
          editOption.setAttribute("href","editNew.jsp?idEvento=" + data[k].idEvento)

         if(data[k].estado === 3){
             optionsColumn.appendChild(deleteOption)
             optionsColumn.appendChild(restoreOption)
         }else if(data[k].estado === 1){
             optionsColumn.appendChild(editOption)
             optionsColumn.appendChild(hideOption)
             optionsColumn.appendChild(deleteOption)
         }

         titleColumn.textContent = data[k].titulo
         datePost.textContent = data[k].fechaPublicacion

         row.appendChild(titleColumn)
         row.appendChild(datePost)
         row.appendChild(optionsColumn)

         table.row.add(row).draw(false)

       }

}
```

Aquí, en esta función configuro el datatable

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){



    table = $('#example').DataTable({
        scrollY: '100vh',
        ordering: false,
        "lengthChange": false,
        dom: '<"filter-search-wrapper group" f> <table><"#length">',
        oLanguage: {
            "sSearch": "",
            "sZeroRecords": "No hay registros"
        }
    });

    scrollBody = document.querySelector(".dataTables_scrollBody")
    maxVisibleElements = Math.floor(scrollBody.offsetHeight / 15)

    rootPropertiesRowHeigth.setAttribute("style","--row-height: " + maxVisibleElements + "px")

    console.log("Alto de fila por elemento: " + maxVisibleElements)

    customizeFilterInput();

    eventoController.getNoticias(putNewsInDataTable,15,true)

    scrollBody.addEventListener("scroll",function(event){
      if(event.target.scrollTop === event.target.scrollTopMax){
         eventoController.getNoticias(putNewsInDataTable)
      }
    })


})
```

Estas son las variables globables que tengo:.

```
let table 
let scrollBody 
let maxVisibleElements
```

Es todo lo que hay en el fichero

Ahora muestro el codigo donde obtengo los datos con fetch:

```
    getNoticias(controllerGetNoticias,rowsLength = 0,isFirstTime){    

      fetch(this.dirResources["get_noticias"] + rowsLength,{method: "GET"}).then(function(response){    
        if(response.ok){
           response.json().then(function(data){             

               if(data.length != 0){
                    if(isFirstTime){
                       let pro = document.querySelector(".progress-b")
                       pro.classList.add("progress-hidden")  
                    }
                    controllerGetNoticias(data)
                }
              })
            }
        })
   }
```

ControllergetNoticias es la funcion que ya mostre arriba donde mando el arreglo que saque apartir del json obtenido del servlet, la variable isFirstTime la utilizo cuando es primera vez que carga la pagina, necesito ocultar una progressbar y asi lo hago. el datatable se va llenando conforme el usuario llega al bottom de la tabla y ahi mando otra peticion, la segunda vez isFirstTime ya no es true.

ya he verificado que no sea un problema de Backend hice pruebas con JUnit y la paginacion funciona bien devuelve 16 elementos la primera vez y funciona bien la consulta.

¿Cual es mi error?, ¿porque el datatable no dibuja los 16 elementos?, ¿en que estoy mal?

Yo no se si estare configurando mal el datatable. Mi idea es que el datatable no me pagine resultados, ni me oculte filas, hagan de cuenta y caso que si 1000 filas traigo las 1000 filas se mostraran de volada y con el scroll se iran viendo. Quiero que no haya paginacion y con el scroll ir viendo todo y si quiero mas registros, debo llegar hasta el bottom de la tabla y asi mandar la peticion y por mi cuenta agregar esas filas nuevas al datatable usando la funcion que ya enseñe arriba.

Una muestra, me devuelve 16, solo se dibujan 10....Ese log lo meti en el bucle donde recorro el arreglo de objetos...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Bien, logre resolver mi problema, debía inhabilitar la paginacion y lo hice con la siguiente propiedad, ahora todas las filas son mostradas.

```
paging: false
```